# I can't download the product image

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to know how I can download the second product image, as it is inside a TAG in quotes.

An alternative would also be to just copy the image link to save in a DF.

[Link Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4qcT.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import pyautogui
import urllib.request
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://shopee.com.br/Tapete-Sala-1-00-X-1-50-Peludo-Shaggy-Macio-Quarto-Felpudo-        
i.346235717.7779211526")
driver.maximize_window()

df = pd.read_excel (r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Shopee\Videos\Videos.xlsx")


for index, row in df.iterrows():
links = driver.get(str(row["links"]))
sleep(5)
video = driver.find_element(By. CLASS_NAME, "_1OPdfl")
sleep(5)
atributoSrc = video.get_attribute("src")
print(atributoSrc)
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(atributoSrc,r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Shopee\Videos     
Baixados\nome" +  str(row["salvar"]) + ".mp4")

    
except:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should download all the product images:

```
#import requests  

imgDivs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._1OPdfl > ._2PWsS4')
for i in range(len(imgDivs)):
    d = imgDivs[i].get_attribute('style')
    imgUrl = d.split('url("')[1].split('")')[0]
    with open(f"img_{i}.jpeg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(imgUrl).content)
        f.close()
    print(imgUrl)
```

The enlarged image gets downloaded twice. You can change the `find_elements` arguments to be pickier about the images.

EDIT: to reduce duplicates you *might* try this:

```
def getImgUrl(imgDiv):
    d = imgDiv.get_attribute('style')
    iUrl = d.split('url("')[1].split('")')[0]
    if iUrl.endswith('_tn'): 
        iUrl = iUrl[:-3]
    return iUrl

imgDivs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._1OPdfl > ._2PWsS4')
imgUrls = [getImgUrl(iDiv) for iDiv in imgDivs]
imgUrls = list(set(imgUrls))  # keep only unique urls
imgTot = len(imgUrls)

for i in range(imgTot):
    imgUrl = imgUrls[i]
    with open(f"img_{i}.jpeg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(imgUrl).content)
        f.close()
    print(f'{i+1} of {imgTot} links: ', imgUrl)
```

since the link to the thumbnail seems to be the same as for the enlarged version - but with '_tn' added to the end. BUT, if they change their naming conventions this might cause errors

Comment: I answered below the code repeats many times, infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

thanks, following your logic, I'll build my own line of codes that worked

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import pyautogui
import urllib.request
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com.br")
driver.maximize_window()

df = pd.read_excel (r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas                     
Python\Shopee\Videos\LinksAfiliado.xlsx")

Link = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

links = driver.get(str(row["links"]))
sleep(5)    
classe = driver.find_element(By. CLASS_NAME, "_3DKwBj")
sleep(5)
atributo = classe.get_attribute("style")
link_imagem = atributo.split('url("')[1].split('")')[0]

print(link_imagem)

Link.append(link_imagem)
      
data = {'Link Imagem': Link} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Shopee\Videos\linkimagens.xlsx", 
engine='xlsxwriter')   
print(df)
```